# How to set slider only on Homepage in Drupal 7.31?

Tags: php, drupal-7, slider

I set my slider only on Homepage with  tag in Drupal 7.31 but it black div is taking same div space on other page but slider is not coming. Help me.
I'm using "Bartik" theme.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display specific content on your drupal homepage than add following code in your `page.tpl.php` file or you can do it using create `Block region position`.

```
<?php 
if (drupal_is_front_page()) { 
     // your slider code goes here
}
?>
```

Comment: I set it but its div is taking same width and height on otherpages. How can I remove this blank div from others pages ? Here I use "Block region position". @hardik Solanki

Answer (score 0):

If your content is a block, go in the settings of your block and choose the option :  display only on listed pages, in listed page add the value `<front>`